# "/usr/libexec/mutter-x11-frames" gpu memory leak on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nvidia, 23.04, memory-leak

is it just me that this process is causing vram memory leak? few software are relying on it including thunderbird, discord, jetbrains rider and maybe more

for example whenever i close/open discord, the vram usage just keeps adding up constantly, usually i have to manually kill this process and restart it, once it even reached 5 gb vram usage, which i check using "nvidia-smi" in terminal, this issue remains in both wayland and x11

Ubuntu 23.04 (not an upgrade, fresh install)

nvidia rtx 2070 using 525 drivers

ryzen 5 5600

32 gb ram

Comment: Yeah, I just saw in nvidia-smi: /usr/libexec/mutter-x11-frames  3348MiB. 
That's 3GB of my GPU memory..!! I only have 8GB, so this takes almost half. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: "is it just me that this process is causing vram memory leak?" we do not accept questions asking for a yes or a no. If yes you need to collect data and file a bugreport.  We can not fix this; nvidia drivers are nvidia's problem, open source driver probably the people at phoronix.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2018731